# Gastby GraphQL ImageSharp get image properties (Origin, Date Taken)

Tags: graphql, gatsby, graphql-js, gatsby-plugin

I am building a Gatsby.js website that has two (and potentially more) types of content: text and images. The images are saved as a series of JPG files in a directory. I have access to them via the gatsby-source-filesystem plugin defined in my `gatsby-config.js` file:

```js
{
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `content-images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/content/images`,
      },
},
```

Using the GraphiQL IDE, I am attempting to build a GraphQL query that accesses these images and sorts them by their original "Date taken" property:

[image]

Unfortunately, through all my research I have been unable to turn up a strategy for accessing this value using GraphQL. Right now, I am exploring the `allFile` route, but none of the fields I try are correct. `birthTime` appears to be when I added the file to the repo. `cTime` the same thing.

Here's a look at what I am working with:

[image]

Is there a field or method that I am missing?

I have `gatsby-transformer-sharp` and `gatsby-plugin-sharp` installed as well, although I am not sure if these plugins would be helpful in this case.

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: How's your data structure? JSON, markdown, CMS?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've updated the post with more contextual information that may be helpful. Right now, I am looking to build a graphQL query. `allFile` is the route that I am using, but none of the available fields seem right.

Comment: Are you sure that is not one of the showed dates but converted in your timezone? Just a guess because you can see the rest of the data so...

Comment: I'm afraid you're looking for image metadata, data encoded inside file content (EXIF, IPTC), not externally available data

Comment: @xadm Hmmm okay. Might it be possible to add the data to the file node via Gatsby's [node api](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-node/#onCreateNode) `onCreateNode` method? Seems like you can insert additional node fields, but I haven't come across a way to access that particular file property.

Comment: @FerranBuireu Unfortunately, I don't think those times are what I am looking for. Even if they were a few hours off, the date times should still be for Sept. 2020.

Comment: a bit of search ... https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-sharp/#exif-and-icc-metadata